# Bug in VSTO - Combobox in worksheet scrolling down with no reason

Tags: vb.net, excel, drop-down-menu, combobox, vsto

Take a look at the code below. This code works perfectly, placing a combobox at the cell A1, that gives you a list of items.

```
Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet
Dim sheet1 As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
sheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet1)

Dim combo As New Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
'combo.AutoCompleteMode = Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
combo.AutoCompleteSource = Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
combo.Items.AddRange({"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test27", "test28", "test29", "test30", "test31", "test32", "test33", "test34"})
Me.sheet.Controls.AddControl(combo, Me.sheet.Range("$A$1"), "test")
```

The problem happens when you uncomment the code line that sets the AutoCompleteMode to SuggestAppend.

To see the bug happening, you need to make your list of items large enough to the scroll appears. Then, you click at the arrow (to open the dropdown menu) and select the first item of the dropdown menu. Do it again, scroll to the last element, and click at this one. Repeat the operation.

At the second iteration doing this, you should see the bug. The list scrolls automatically when you press the mouse button, changing the element that is under the cursor. Then, when you release the mouse button, you select an item that is not your desired element.

Does someone knows a workaround for this problem? I'm using VS2013, and programming with VB.NET (as you can see, hehe).

Thanks

Comment: Someone can help me? I just don't know what to do about that...

Comment: Which version of Excel, please ?

Comment: Excel 2013. The problem still happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by "jmierzej" [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1dbe9f32-b68c-47db-832d-7835b583b03a/combobox-in-worksheet-scrolling-with-no-reason?forum=vsto&prof=required)

**Solution:**

I first added all my items to a Dictionary object, and then I bound the combobox to that Dictionary.  In the below code, the 'prefill' object is the Dictionary object which holds the combobox contents.

```
    'define the dictionary which will hold the values
    Dim prefill = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    'add code here to fill Dictionary with your items.  In my case I used identical values for the key/value pair in the Dictionary

    cbox.DataSource = New BindingSource(prefill, Nothing)
    cbox.DisplayMember = "Value"
    cbox.ValueMember = "Key"
```